# Getting value in database from a range of dates with that value not having appeared outside of that range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Our database stores call data, with a datetime value for when the call was made along with the phone number used to call. I was wondering how I could get all of the phone numbers that have made calls within the past hour and that have not made calls before. I tried to use the following query with no success:

```
select distinct(calling_number)
from calldb.call_logs
where call_started >= sysdate-1/24
and calling_number not in
(
select distinct(calling_number)
from calldb.call_logs
where call_started < sysdate-1/24
)
```

Example of what I would like to accomplish:
Assuming the database has the following data and the current time is 2:30 am

```
calling_number  call_started
9497587364      1:24 am
5719389402      1:25 am
7418320194      1:33 am
7584729818      1:34 am
9497587364      1:36 am
```

The result would be

```
7418320194      
7584729818
```

since both of those numbers appear within the past hour and haven't appeared in the database before. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried the query you shared? It should produce the correct answer.

Comment: @mathguy The result is empty. I thought there was something wrong with the query because I'm almost certain there should be some result that matches, but maybe I'm mistaken

Comment: Can the `calling_number` be `NULL`? Don't guess, find out by running a small query: `select count(*) from call_logs where calling_number is null`. This is the kind of data that will make `not in` the wrong choice. (If you are asking for something to be `not in` a list and the list includes `NULL`, you are not guaranteed that the thing you are comparing is not on the list, since `NULL` could be anything.)

Comment: @mathguy Yes, they can be null. So that means that I shouldn't be using not in for this task? Is there another way that you know of that will let me achieve this? Could I just add "and calling_number is not null" to query I'm comparing to?

Comment: Yes, that is one way - add "and calling_number is not null" in the subquery you are comparing to. Also in the same subquery you don't need to select **distinct**; that actually wastes time, it doesn't save it. Try both ways and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Common Table Expressions. Use the WITH() clause to make two subqueries. The first will look at every phone number that has called within the last hour. The second will use an aggregate function to count how many calls that particular number has made before.

From there, you select all of your distinct phone numbers from the RecentCalls CTE, then in the WHERE clause use your `NOT IN (SELECT ... FROM CallTotals)` statement to exclude everything from your second table that had a count of 1 (>1 signifies that they have called before).

```
WITH RecentCalls AS (
    SELECT calling_number
    FROM calldb.call_logs
    WHERE calling_number IS NOT NULL AND call_started >= sysdate - 1/24),
CallTotals AS (
    SELECT calling_number, COUNT(calling_number) AS call_count
    FROM calldb.call_logs
    WHERE calling_number IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY calling_number)
SELECT DISTINCT calling_number
FROM RecentCalls
WHERE calling_number NOT IN (SELECT calling_number FROM CallTotals WHERE call_count = 1)
```